# Default Order of My Sites Pages in Google?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a brand new site. I have around 100 pages. I have a home page, I have Tag pages, I have category pages, and I have articles. Categories make up the navigation, and tags are on each article to help users navigate. I have no inbound external links.

When I google site:mysite.com it lists all of my pages.

My home page is first, then all of my tag pages, and then category and articles mixed together at the end.

I don't really care about this order, but I just want to make sure I haven't done anything wrong and given my tag pages too much weight. I really would like the weight to be on the articles. Should I be worried about this serp order?

This is my first ever question, and I am sorry if it is not clear. I also wan't sure if I am allowed to put my URL, I am happy to include it if needed.

Comment: By the way to answer your second question, I believe I saw a thread a while back that established that the etiquette on this forum is not to post your URL. This forum only accepts questions that are applicable to future readers and not just the asker's own site, anyway, so the etiquette makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the order of your pages when you do a Google `site:` query. Google's ranking algorithm is powered by the user's search intent (there is no intent when you use a `site:` query). When a user does a real search, your pages will always show up in the order that Google believes is the most relevant for the user's query.

Comment: Not worrying about the order seems to be the answer. I marked this as accepted.
I am still curious as to the default order, as having all the tags first seems a little more organised than random. Also, your additional comment about future readers makes sense and was as I suspected.

Comment: @BrettEldridge It might order based on number of internal links, or some other metric. Us mere mortals can only speculate.